# how to fix issue when magento upgrade from 2.3.4 to 2.4.3?

Tags: upgrade, magento-2.3, magento2.4

### I'd like to upgrade magento from 2.3.4 to 2.4.3.
But I cannot upgrade it.
this is error.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 requires php ~7.3.0||~7.4.0 -> your php version (7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer ^0.5.0 -> satisfiable by dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer[v0.5.0].
- dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.2.0] but it does not match the constraint.

### Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

### I am using cpanel now. In cpanel I set php version is 7.4

### PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Nov 10 2022 11:12:07) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

See if you're really using php 7.4 by typing `php -v` in the terminal. When you are sure that your php version is correct, delete the **composer.*lock*** file (*make a backup beforehand*). Try updating with the command:

> composer require magento/product-community-edition:2.4.5 -W

If that doesn't work, post the contents of the **composer.*json*** file

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating from 2.3.4 to 2.4.3, you need to make the following and please follow these below steps:

1: Backup composer.json: Run the command

`cp composer.json composer.json.bak`

2: Upgrade your Magento: Run the commmand

```
composer require-commerce magento/<product> <version> --no-update [--interactive-root-conflicts] [--force-root-updates] [--help]
```

3: Update the dependecies:

composer update

For example, Specify the metapackage:

Magento Open Source: `composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update`

Adobe Commerce: `composer require-commerce magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.4 --no-update`

4: Composer Update: Run `composer update`

5: Update the database schema and data. `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

6: Disable Magento maintenance mode. `bin/magento maintenance:disable`

7: Restart Varnish. (Optional) Restart Varnish If you use it for page caching: `service varnish restart`

Please switch to PHP 7.4 first then check perform the upgrade.